# How can I upload image and other form data using stream_context_create function with PUT method

Tags: image, curl, upload, put

I am using below function to post data and image on remote server.

```
function do_post_request_put($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
{
  $params = array('http' => array(
          'method' => 'PUT',
          'content' => $data
        ));
  if ($optional_headers !== null) {
    $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
  }

  $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
  $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
  if (!$fp) {
    throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
  if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  return $response;
}
```

I am calling function as below.

```
$arr[user][full_name]=$_POST[full_name];

$arr[user][email]=$_POST[email];

$arr[user][password]=$_POST[password];

$arr[user][profile_picture]=$_FILES[image];

$post_arr=http_build_query($arr);

$resp=do_post_request_put($url, $post_arr, $optional_headers = null);
```

Comment: then what is the problem you are facing had you tried with the code

Comment: image upload is not working at remote server.  email,password parameters received at server side